# How to use a redirect 127.0.0.1 to docker machine IP

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm setting up a `docker-compose` environment for a web application which responds to a wildcard subdomain. On development, we simply use the great `lvh.me` domain (which resolves to 127.0.0.1) and it works for all subdomains without any extra configuration, eg:

- app.lvh.me:3000
- app2.lvh.me:3000
- app-watherever.lvh.me:3000

My question is how to set up a custom domain (let's say `app.local`) and all its subdomains to resolve to the `docker-machine ip`.

Note: I don't want to use the `etc/hosts` as it'll require to add each subdomain individually to the file.

Comment: How's your DNS structure currently? Do you have a catch-all entry redirecting to your docker-machine ip? I'm assuming you want remote users to access it (prod environment)

Comment: This is a setup for the development env. The production env works fine with a catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of your domains (or buy a cheap one) with a DNS hosting service.

If your docker machine's ip is dynamic, you'll need a hosting service that supports Dynamic DNS, or a regular DNS service with for an A record pointing to the static ip.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually particularly related to Docker.

Be aware that doing this with a '.local' domain suffix will prevent you from getting a TLS certificate from a publicly-trusted authority, and will cause you to have to modify your environment to have to trust a local certificate authority, which then issues certificates to your docker-machine's hosted domain.  If you have an IT department, I *strongly recommend* you speak to them; if they deny the request, talk to your manageer and and have them push for it.

The basic steps are as follows:

1. Set up a local DNS server that you can point your resolver to.
2. Configure it to forward queries that it can't itself answer to your current DNS servers.
3. Set up an "app.local" zone that contains a few records.  (In the SOA record, your email address should be written with a dot instead of an @ symbol, and with a trailing dot.  All full DNS names written in here must have a trailing dot.  And also, swap '127.19.20.201' for whatever your docker-machine IP is):

```
app.local.    IN       SOA  60  yourmachinename your.email.address.  (
                       2019102100    ; serial number: YYYYMMDDss where ss is sequence
                       3600          ; refresh interval, not important here
                       1800          ; retry interval, not important here
                       3600          ; record expiration, not important here
                       60            ; minimum record time-to-live
)
app.local.    IN       A    60  172.19.20.201
*.app.local.  IN       A    60  172.19.20.201
```

4. Change your OS resolver to point to that local DNS server.  (If you're on Windows, this operation requires elevation.  Otherwise, if you're using bind, it's in /etc/resolv.conf.)

If you need to do this on more than just your own machine, *talk to your IT department*.  They are the ones with the power (though not necessarily the willingness, unless your manager pressures them into it) to set this zone up for all the machines which use their DNS server.  Business justifications ('we need it to behave like our main app, but on a different host and domain name') trump ideological correctness (though '.local' as a TLD is reserved in the DNS RFCs), though they cannot trump protocol mandates.

(If you need a TLS certificate for this development -- and you really probably do! -- you should also talk to your IT department.  They can get a free wildcard certificate from LetsEncrypt by verifying control of the DNS zone.  Learning how that's done can take between 15 and 30 minutes, and setting up the environment can take 15 minutes to 6 hours depending on the DNS provider in use.)